# Regular expression. If Part of URL after /category/ starts with digits return true. How?

Tags: php, regex

There is some url types:

1. https: //mysite.com/page-title
2. https: //mysite.com/category/page-title
3. https: //mysite.com/category/123-page-title (123 - it's ID of page)

I need to check the URL, whether it starts with the digits (type 3). I.e url = is type 3, then return TRUE.

What kind of regular expression does this require?

Comment: what language php,python,.. ?

Comment: Do you try any regex for this?

Comment: If PHP, then: `echo (int)preg_match('/\.com\/category\/\d+/', $url);`

Comment: Sorry. Language PHP

Comment: You don't need `regex` for this in PHP. Sure, it's only one line of code with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) vs. 3 lines using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)+[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)+some checks.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the ID can be at any place after the domain address, therefore:

```
false https: //mysite.com/123-page-title
false https: //mysite.com/page-title
false https: //mysite.com/category/page-title
true  https: //mysite.com/category/123-page-title
false  https: //mysite.com/1-page-title
```

Hence the regex you need is: `'/mysite\.com.*/category/\d+?.*/'`

```
mysite\.com.*/\d+?.*
   mysite matches the characters mysite literally (case sensitive)
   \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
   com matches the characters com literally (case sensitive)
 .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    /category/ matches the characters /category/ literally (case sensitive)
    \d+? matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
      +? Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
 .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
   * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/qv8tim/2

Comment: In the title of the question, the poster specifies "If Part of URL after /category/ starts with digits return true." So your assumption that "the ID can be at any place after the domain address" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for a regular expression to meet this requirement is as follows:

`.*?category\/[0-9]+.*`

This will match anything up to the phrase `category/`, then require that at least one number follows, and then matches the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody loves regular expressions :-)

A solution that doesn't use `regex`:

```
function is_valid($url)
{
    $pieces = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
    return isset($pieces[2]) && (int)$pieces[2];
}
```

See it in action: https://3v4l.org/BqcTs

Comment: While this is a good answer, the asker did request information specific to regular expressions.

Comment: @Regexr the asker needs a way to identify the URLs that match some rules. They have heard that regular expressions are good for such things but they don't have any idea how to write a `regex` and how to use it. The regular expressions are a powerful tool for very specific jobs, they are not a one-size-fit-all tool.